# Using TV remote with Chrome app running on ChromeBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I have a custom Chrome app running on an Asus ChromeBox and was wondering if there was anyway to use the TV remote (it's an LG TV) to interact with the web app?

We have a wireless keyboard and mouse, but I'd like to know if there is a way to use the remote, meaning some basic functions can be assigned to a single key press, and the keyboard + mouse do not have to be used (e.g. the app runs as a kiosk app and might occasionally require a function to clear the users localstorage and a keyboard is not available)

Answer (score 0):

TV remotes generally use Infrared (IR) technology to send the signal to the TV, while media boxes and computers generally use bluetooth or proprietary technologies like RC-6.

You can probably use your LG remote on the ChromeBox, but you will need an IR to USB dongle, like this one: [http://www.amazon.com/FLIRC-FL-09028-Universal-Receiver-Components/dp/B00BB0ETW8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1437406599&sr=8-1&keywords=usb+ir+receiver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BB0ETW8)

Good luck!

Comment: So with that do you think it'd be possible to capture the key presses within my app?

Comment: The USB dongle will convert the IR signal from the remote to a format your ChromeBox can understand. You should then be able to use standard key logging techniques within your app to see how the remote buttons get interpreted by the OS.

Comment: Sounds spot on, although I just realised, the TV itself would still pick up key presses, so it makes the whole thing invalid ha!

Comment: True, unless your remote has a switch or a mode distinction for controlling VCR or other devices which you are not using. I never thought about the TV picking up the button presses tho XD

Comment: Even worse is that the TV remote could be any brand, as the customers can plug the ChromeBox into any TV they want.